# TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimiter'

Tags: python, json, pandas, delimiter

I am trying to delimit a flat json file in Python 3 (via Jupyter), in order to create an extra column. Pandas automatically reads and produces rows between "...". When I print without a delimiter it reads the file just fine. Here the first four rows:

```
0                             <h1>lorum ipsum|
1                              <h2>lorum ipsum|
2                                                     
3    <h5>lorum ipsum...
```

However, I would like to separate an extra column every time json has file a >, but I receive an extensive error I do not understand. What am I doing wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-647ecd72fd56> in <module>
      1 import sys
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 df = pd.read_json('/filepath/doc.json' , delimiter='>', engine='python', header=None)
      4 print (df)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimiter'
```

Code that produces error is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('/path/file.json' , delimiter='>', engine='python', header=None)
print (df)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) outlines the arguments you can use with `pd.read_json` and `delimiter`, `engine` and `header` is not one of them.

Comment: You'll need to split the column after you've loaded the data.

Comment: Can you add a small sample JSON file for testing?

Answer (score 0):

@Ron

Sure. It was originally a pdf, which I scraped into json, the best I could. With headers, sub headers and paragraphs.

```
["<h1>Amsterdam Circulair|", "<h2>leren door te doen|", "", "<h5>In 2 jaar met ruim 20 projecten in de praktijk laten zien dat het kan|", "<h5>2|", "", "<s1>Voorpagina:| Een medewerkster van Gro-Holland verzamelt de op koffieprut | gegroeide oesterzwammen, waarna zij naar de restaurants van La | Place gaan, de leverancier van de koffieprut. Foto: Olaf Kraak.| Bron: Trouw|", "", "<h2>Inhoud|", "", "<h5>Voorwoord| 4|", "<h5>1 | Inleiding | 6|", "<h5>2 |  Wat hebben het onderzoek en de marktconsultatie opgeleverd? | 7|", "", "<p>2.1  | Onderzoeksrapport Amsterdam Circulair | 7|", "<p>2.2 | Resultaat marktconsultatie | 7|", "<p>2.3 | Duurzaamheidsraad | 8|", "", "<h5>3 | Wat doen we al? | 9|", "<h5> 4 | Hoe gaan we verder? | 10|", "", "<p>4.1  | Inzet gemeente  | 10|", "<p>4.2 | Inzet 2016-2017 uitgewerkt | 12|", "<p>4.3 | Wat vragen we anderen | 18|", "", "<s1>4.3.1 | Rijk | 18|", "<s1>4.3.2 | Bedrijfsleven | 18|", "<s1>4.3.3 | Amsterdammers | 18|", "", "<h5>5 | Samengevat | 19|", "", "<p>Versie 16 november 2016|", "<h5>3|", "", "<h2>Voorwoord|", "", "<p>De transformatie van onze huidige economie naar een duurzame, circulaire economie is noodzakelijk en onontkoombaar. De | \u2018circulaire economie\u2019 is anno 2016 nog een toekomstbeeld. De vraag die nu voorligt is daarom: hoe moeilijk of makkelijk gaan we | het elkaar maken om dit toekomstbeeld om te zetten in realiteit?|", "<p>Vast staat dat de overheid niet kan bepalen dat \u2018de\u2019 economie maar circulair moet worden, maar dat ze een faciliterende en | stimulerende taak heeft. Juist bedrijven en instellingen moeten hun rol kunnen pakken in een economie in transitie.|", "<p>De bijdrage die de gemeente Amsterdam daarom op dit moment het beste kan leveren, is aantonen dat de circulaire economie | werkelijkheid kan worden. Dit gaan we doen door de komende twee jaar met twintig projecten te laten zien dat circulair werken | kan.
```